# Javascript - define function with variable

Tags: variables, if-statement, javascript

Let's say I have the following code

```
var $variable = $('<li/>', { 
    tabindex: 0,
    click: function() {
        //more code in here
    }
}
```

is it possible to define the `click:` with a variable? Baring in mind it is already inside a variable and will also include an if statement, like so:

```
if(condition) {
    var functiontype = 'click';
}
else {
    var functiontype = 'hover';
}
var $variable = $('<li/>', { 
    tabindex: 0,
    functiontype: function() {
        //more code in here
    }
}
```

I tried doing this but it didn't work. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(condition) {
    var functiontype = 'click';
}
else {
    var functiontype = 'hover';
}

var options = {};
options["tabindex"] = 0;
options[functiontype] = function(){
    // your code
}
var $variable = $('<li/>', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do the reverse :

```
var $variable = $('<li/>', { 
    tabindex: 0
};
$variable[condition?'click':'hover'] = function(){
   // the code here
}
```